# Consuming Odata service with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, odata

I'd like to consume an [odata](http://www.odata.org/) service with a .NET Compact Framework 3.5 client application. What's the easiest way to do that? There are are clients for various programming languages in the odata SDK, but I could not find anything related to the compact framework.

Am I missing something or do I have to use plain old HttpWebRequests?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out after posting social.msdn.com, there really is no .net Compact framework client library for odata. So it looks like HttpWebRequests really are the way to go.

Comment: Your question shows on top in google and is quite outdated. Do you have anything new on the matter?

Comment: Also, for anyone interrested, here's the link to the said post ;) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/471d468a-b97a-49f1-9ba9-2acbd64a75a7/consuming-odata-services-also-known-as-wcf-data-services?forum=netfxcompact